# Gfortran warning: change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4)!

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm using an old fortran script (accessible [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6GUNg-8d30vRnhpaDlsUmgwLXM/view?usp=sharing)). I'm receiving the following warnings (line#192, 233-235). Is there a way to fix it? I'm using *gfortran 6* on my mac.

```
Ms-MacBook-Pro-2:~ Tonoy$ gfortran -g -fcheck=all -Wall mrtm.f
mrtm.f:192:8:

       N=COL/DX
        1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
mrtm.f:233:10:

       NKK=TPRINT/DT+0.50D0
          1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
mrtm.f:234:10:

       KLM=TTOTAL/DT+0.50D0
          1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
mrtm.f:235:9:

       KK=KLM/NKK+0.5D0
         1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]
```

Comment: Assignment of a float to an integer results in truncation of fractional part and maybe magnitude/overflow as well.

Comment: Use tag fortran to get more attention.

Comment: Your [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6GUNg-8d30vRnhpaDlsUmgwLXM/view?usp=sharing) is not accessible. It gives me a button that says "request access".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the variables N, NKK, KLM, and KK are all being implicitly declared as integers. The right hand side of the assignment, however, includes numbers that are explicitly REAL*8. So essentially what is happening is the compiler is evaluating the right hand side of each of these lines as a REAL*8, but then trying to assign the resulting value to an integer. If any non-zero digits live after the decimal point, they will be lost in this conversion/assignment.

In the assignment, the compiler will simply ignore the decimal point and any digits that come thereafter. In a lot of old fortran code, this was the expected behavior, and the code consequently is doing what it was intended to do.

If you simply want to get rid of the compile warnings, you can encapsulate the right hand side of the assignment with an INT, i.e.

```
N=INT(COL/DX)
NKK=INT(TPRINT/DT+0.50D0)
KLM=INT(TTOTAL/DT+0.50D0)
KK=INT(KLM/NKK+0.5D0)
```

Comment: This worked for me, which [resolved some warnings that I was not getting in GCC 9.3.0 but was getting in GCC 4.8.5](https://gitlab.com/Molcas/OpenMolcas/-/merge_requests/580#note_1223069634).